# Add SQLite db as attachment when sending mail

Tags: android, sqlite, object, gmail

I want to mail a backup of the db. Is it possible to do this without saving the sql db as a file on the tablet? So adding the SQLitedatabse object directely as attachement.

Right now i'm saving the db as a file and sending it as attachment.

Code:

```
 public void sendMail(String filepath) {

        String[] recipients = {"mail adres"};
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));

        // prompts email clients only
        email.setType("message/rfc822");

        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "DBBackup");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "DBBackupB");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getFile(filepath));
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send email"));


    }
```

Comment: Not via an Intent. The database file is in the internal storage that is private to your app so it has to be copied to an external location in order for the app that consumes the intent to be able to read it. You'll need to implement your own emailing code - a search should bring up some libraries/source that you can use.

Comment: another way would be implement a ContentProvider to give the e-mail app access to your file. But that sounds like an overkill for me. Just put in the android/data/<package.name>/ folder that it will stay hidden enough until you have time to delete it.

Comment: I want to delete the db from external storage after mailing it. is it possible to know when the email is actually send?

Comment: So if i understand it correctly, it isn't possible to get the db from internal storage an mail it because of safety reasons, but i can copy the db to external storage and then mail is? Isn't the second options actually more unsafe?

Comment: There is no way to know when the email is sent. The user could leave the share chooser or their email client open for any amount of time before completing the process. As Budius suggests, just put the file somewhere reasonably obscure and clear that directory out each time your app starts.

Comment: The reason you can't share out from internal storage is system security - apps cannot directly access another app's data, unless allowed to via a ContentProvider. Your app copying a file to external storage does not impact system security, only the security of your app's data which is your responsibility to manage. Sometimes, like in this case where an intent is the simplest solution, you have to decide if the compromise is worth it.

Comment: It seems that i can access the sql database directly from the internal storage and add it as attachment if i modify the following property's of te file: rVal.setReadable(true,false); rVal.setWritable(true, false);. after the file is added as attachment, i can simply make it unreadable/unwritable by making the same property's false. But which method is actually safer? copying the file to external storage and deleting it after use, or making the file in the internal storage temporary readable/writable.